# xCode Sqlite Database Creation Without Z_METADATA

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, metadata

When my sqlite database is created using a core data model, at this line:

```
 if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
```

I get an error:

```
 NSUnderlyingException=I/O SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA'
```

Any idea how to fix this?  I've been trying for days.  The database is created and copied into the documents directory on my device.

Note:

If I DELETE the application, rebuild, and install on my device - the .sqlite file is dated two days ago and the .mom file is dated yesterday.   Is the database not recreated at compile time if necessary?  I have no .sqlite file in my project, just the .xcdatamodel.

Thanks for your time.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    //\MOVES DATABASE TO NEW LOCATION
    NSString *storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myShoeDatabase.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // If the expected store doesn’t exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myShoeDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Can you show your code that creates the PSC (`initWithManagedObjectModel:`)

Comment: How was the SQLite persistent store database created?  You can't just use any old SQLite database, it needs to be in the exact format generated by Core Data.

Comment: I added my code.  I am using the database that is created by core data.  Thanks for your interest and help Brad, falcon, and MPelletier.

Comment: After inspecting from the command line using sqlite> .schema, I can only see this: "CREATE TABLE "locations" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"name" varchar(50),"lon" FLOAT,"lat" FLOAT);"

Comment: That does not look like a core data store at all. Do you have location entities in your MOM?

Comment: Yes  There are two entities and location is one of them.  I think I might have solved it.  I deleted the build folder and the application from my device.  I think it was still grabbing the old .sqlite from my build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please start with this basic sanity check: Bring the database to your Mac, open it with sqlite3.exe, and see if the table is present.

If it is, then your program is pointing to the wrong database.
If it is not, then your table was never created (or the database is corrupt as hell, but that would be surprising).

Comment: I can transfer the database from my device to my Mac and open it with Firefox's SQLite Manager with no problem.  I am not sure how I can be pointing to the wrong database when Core Data creates the database and I successfully copy it to the documents folder (verified by browsing my device files).

Answer (score 0):

Core Data seems to look for the metadata first when it opens a store so a complaint about the Z_METADATA usually indicates a corrupted file or a file in the wrong format. I would suspect either a problem with the copied file (permission, corruption etc) or a problem with the `options` for the store.

I would suggest:

1. Open the store as readonly in the app bundle i.e. without copying it and see if it opens fine. If it does, then the problem is in the copying.
2. Provide an error to the copy method and log its return. The copy might be subtly failing.
3. Get the size of the copied file. The file might end up in the directory but empty.
4. Pass a `nil` options dict to make sure that is not the problem.

Comment: 1. The app bundle store gives the same result
2. The copy is working perfectly
3. The sizes of both the copied file and default file are 8kb
4. I originally passed nil and I get the same error.

Thanks for your suggestions.  Any others?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to catch these errors and at least report them:

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
```

Also, that method returns a BOOL of success or failure, you should be watching for that as well.

Beyond that, assuming the sqlite file is valid, there is nothing overtly wrong with the code.  Can you duplicate this in a sample application?  If so, you can post a link to it in your question and I will be happy to tinker around with it.  If it turns out to be an Apple bug you will then have the test case ready for your radar.  If it doesn't duplicate in a test then you can compare the differences to see what is wrong in the original application.